# ASP.NET membership/SQLMembershipProvider Source Code

Tags: asp.net, membership, sqlmembershipprovider

In the SQLMembershipProvider source for ASP.NET membership, there is a custom exception, MembershipPasswordException.

The definition of it is not part of the source, but when I do a goto definition on it, it opens the definition, which indicates: [from metatdata] and the file it came from is a dll, system.web.dll from a temporary directory.

How did that get there or was it part of the msi install that the toolkit provider came with?

Answer (score 3):

When using Reflector I saw that it's directly in the `System.Web.Security` namespace. When you take a look at the code and Visual Studio notices it's already in an assembly it knows about and you digg deeper on it it'll open it's metadata.

Answer (score 2):

Both `SqlMembershipProvider` and `MembershipPasswordException` are part of the System.Web assembly and live in the `System.Web.Security` namespace. Microsoft just didn't include the `MembershipPasswordException` in the source code that comes with the toolkit.

Comment: I'm guessing that the source/cs file came with the provider toolkit?  If I mouse over the tab, and go to the source directory indicated by it, the file has the same timestamp as the time I installed the toolkit.  I wonder why it's in the temp directory and not part of the source project?  And how does VS know where to go to to retrieve it?  I guess the msi install added a reference somewhere.